# What happens when light travels through consecutively denser mediums?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

When light travels through consecutively rarer mediums, total internal reflection happens. What happens when light travels through consecutively denser mediums?

Comment: What do you mean by *consecutively*? are you referring to a continuous or to a discontinuous change of the refraction index?

Comment: Yeah, it would be quite helpful if you could explain the meaning of  "consecutively". Are you meaning that whether there are any similar effects if light passes from a rarer to denser medium?

Comment: Please add a reference.